# Entitlement policy(PDP) is not working for federated users in WSO2 identity server 5.10.0

Tags: wso2, xacml, pdp, wso2-identity-server

Following is the XACML Entitlement policy for allowing users with **admin** role only

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="role_based_login_policy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
   <Description>This policy template provides ability to authorize users to a given service provider(defined by SP_NAME) in the authentication flow based on the roles of the user (defined by ROLE_1 and ROLE_2). Users who have at least one of the given roles, will be allowed and any others will be denied.</Description>
   <Target>
      <AnyOf>
         <AllOf>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">SP_Name</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/identity/sp/sp-name" Category="http://wso2.org/identity/sp" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Match>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">authenticate</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/identity/identity-action/action-name" Category="http://wso2.org/identity/identity-action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Match>
         </AllOf>
      </AnyOf>
   </Target>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="permit_by_roles">
      <Condition>
         <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:or">
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">admin</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Apply>
         </Apply>
      </Condition>
   </Rule>
   <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="deny_others"></Rule>
</Policy>
```

It works fine when i use default wso2 authentication with local users.

But when i use **Federated authentication**(google in my case), i use **Just-In-Time provisioning** for making local users by storing user in local user store.

After the first login i assign **admin** role to that local user manually.

Now when i login again using federated authentication for the same user, the user still does not pass the Entitlement policy.

Am i making some mistake in writing the policy or is my local user not getting linked to federated user?

Comment: Did you check the authentication with a local user for the same application? It worked fine when I enable the "Assert identity using mapped local subject identifier" option.

Comment: yes i checked with the local user, the policy works fine. Is there any chance that federated user is not getting linked with local user at the time of authorization?

Comment: i get the following log in "audit.log" file when "Authentication attempt fails"

TID: [-1234] [2020-05-14 14:41:25,377] [28ac7728-a35d-4f3f-80d0-03577fbe919a] INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator : null | Action : Login | Target : ApplicationAuthenticationFramework | Data : { "ContextIdentifier" : "d33c81d7-3b2c-48b3-bb9b-76ba6aa9009d","ServiceProviderName" : "jenkins","RequestType" : "oidc","RelyingParty" : "u6wuuERE4btdlATfxglw0E_VhwMa","StepNo" : "0" } | Result : Failed